# Create / Update windows phone store app throw an error "Are you missing assembly refernce"

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have an application on store with the name of Sher o Shayari. Now I want to update that app with bit structure change. I add category screen and comment out code that is not related to new things.

I have screen MainPage.xaml. I comment out all xaml code and changed functionality of this screen. Changed code is working perfect in debug mode. but when I try to create store build for updating application then store build creation display an error.

Error   1   'sher_o_shayari.MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'Valentine' and no extension method 'Valentine' accepting a first argument of type 'sher_o_shayari.MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   2   'sher_o_shayari.MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'Love_Poetry_Images' and no extension method 'Love_Poetry_Images' accepting a first argument of type 'sher_o_shayari.MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have removed methods  "Love_Poetry_Images", "Valentine"  from both mainpage.xaml   and mainpage.xaml.cs.

so why I'm getting this error. [image]

This error display for those event which are now comment out. I don't need those so I removed / Comment out from mainpage.xaml   and mainpage.xaml.cs.

What would be the problem? is this due to my bit structure change or not.? How to resolve this.? Your assistance will be higly appreciated.

Comment: @Chirag Shah  Please have a look at this.

Comment: @user2354187  Would you please let me know that what would eb this error and how to resolve this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution of this error. 
I renamed MainPage.xaml to category.xaml. 
Correctly added Namespace for category.xaml.cs.

Then again tried to create store build. this time no error display and I have submitted app successfully.

Note: Please keep your backup before doing this thing or deleting MainPage.xaml